# Chess: Extracting the principal variation from the transposition table

Tags: algorithm, chess, alpha-beta-pruning

Earlier, I was having an issue involving my principal variation becoming truncated by an alpha-beta search. Indeed, this appears to be a common issue. From the authors of Crafty:

> Another solution with even worse properties is to extract the full PV
>   from the transposition table, and avoid using the triangular array
>   completely.  If the transposition table is large enough so that
>   nothing gets overwritten at all, this would almost work.  But there is
>   a hidden “gotcha”.  Once you search the PV, you continue to search
>   other parts of the tree, and you will frequently encounter some of
>   those same positions again, but the hash draft will not be deep enough
>   to allow the entry to be used.  You continue searching and now have to
>   overwrite that entry (exact hash signature match requires this) and
>   you now leave a transposition “trail” to a different endpoint, one
>   which does not match the original score.  Or any one of the trans/ref
>   entries between the root and the actual PV endpoint get overwritten by
>   a different position completely, and you now have no way to search the
>   transposition table to find the actual endpoint you want to display. 
>   Several use this approach to produce the PV, and the complaints are
>   generally frequent and loud, because an evaluation paired with an
>   unrelated PV is not very useful, either for debugging or for analyzing
>   your own games.

This makes a lot of sense.

Consider that the principal variation is ABCDEF, but AB returns the board to its original position. Then, an alternative line examined later might be CDEFGH, which results in a different evaluation than the earlier search of just CDEF. Thus, the transposition table entry for the board state after AB is overwritten, potentially with a node that will be cut off by alpha-beta (!!), and the PV of ABCDEF is destroyed forever.

Is there any way around this problem, or do I have to use an external data structure to save the PV?

**Specifically, what is wrong with replacing if and only if the new entry is deeper and exact?** This doesn't seem to work, but I'm not sure why.

Comment: I am posting an update for the benefit of readers. I appear to have preserved the principal variation with a combination of two changes:
1) Never replace an exact entry in the transposition table with a cutoff entry. 
2) Always replace an inexact entry with an exact one -- otherwise, we might fail to add a "shallower" ending of a principal variation. 3) Otherwise, use depth. 4) When alpha-beta search doesn't cutoff, it should always add the locally best move to the table. (Even if the move is worse than alpha.) I'm not 100% confident this works in all cases, but my results seem much better.

Comment: You may want to look at https://github.com/official-stockfish/Stockfish/blob/master/src/tt.h